# How to generate array key using array index in for on the associative array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, associative-array

Is it possible to generate array keys using the array index in the "for" to create associative arrays?

I want the values in the index array in the "for" to be used as keys in the associative array

The sample code that you want to get the value for making an associative array is in the middle of the *** sign :

```
                 if(data.status == 422){
                    let msg = data.responseJSON.errors;
                    let msgObject = Object.keys(msg);
                    
                    for (let i = 0; i < msgObject.length; i++) {
                        if (msg[msgObject[i]]) {
                            let msgObjectIndex = msgObject[i];

                            let columnIndex = {
                                       ||
                                       \/
                                ***msgObject[i]*** : column[msgObject[i]]
                                       /\
                                       ||
                            };
                            console.log(columnIndex);
                            
                        }
                    }
                }else {
                    alert('Please Reload to read Ajax');
                    console.log("ERROR : ", e);
                    }
                },
```

then variable column is:

```
let column = {
            'nama_paket' : $('.edit_error_nama_paket'), 
            'tipe_berat' : $('.edit_error_tipe_berat'), 
            'harga'      : $('.edit_error_harga'), 
            'id_service' : $('.edit_error_id_service'),
        };
```

I tried the code above to get the following error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '['
thanks

Comment: What is going on in the declaration/assignment of `columnIndex`?  That is for sure illegal syntax.  Is that just there as a hint for this question?  If so, it might be better to just add a comment so your syntax is clear and correct in your example code.

Comment: In this part of your code `column[msgObject[i]]`, what is the meaning of **column**?

Comment: I edited the post, regarding the variable "column"

Comment: You can initialise an object with a computed property name by [surrounding it in square brackets](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/javascript-object-creation-356e504173a8): `columnIndex={ [ msgObject[i] ] : column[msgObject[i]]}`.

Comment: yes that's illegal syntax, I just want to know how to get the value "msgObject [i]" (which is in the middle of the *** sign) and then that value is used as an array key

Comment: wooaaah, that's work "cars10m" thanks for answer :) I suggest you to put this answer in "Answer Question" instead of in this comment

Comment: @Ismynr That's what the answer I gave you 1/2 hour ago does with same terminology of *computed property names*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate computed property names with `[]` syntax

Simple example:

```js
let obj = {};

['a','b','c'].forEach((e,i) => {
  let computed = {[e]:i};
  Object.assign(obj, computed) 
})

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Very minor suggestion but Array.reduce suits this solution better

Comment: @Rajesh Lots of ways to skin a cat

Comment: hence started with "very minor"

Comment: thanks, very simple code `msgObject.forEach((e, i) => {    let columnIndex = {  [e] : column[msgObject[i]] };   console.log(columnIndex);    })`

Answer (score 0):

Here couple of ways you can do, see my comments.

1. one way is as suggested by @charlietlf.
2. After object creation, add the key/value

```
    let msg = data.responseJSON.errors;
    let msgObject = Object.keys(msg);
    
    for (let i = 0; i < msgObject.length; i++) {
      if (msg[msgObject[i]]) {
        let msgObjectIndex = msgObject[i];
    
        const newKey1 = `MyNewKey${2 + 3}`; // sample
        let columnIndex = {
          // One way is
          [newKey1]: column[msgObject[i]],
        };
    
        // Alternatively, we can add the generated key and value to obj
        const newKey2 = msgObject[i];
        //  or something like newKey2 = `MyKey${msgObject[i]}`
        columnIndex[newKey2] = column[msgObject[i]];
    
        console.log(columnIndex);
      }
    }
```